# How do I prove that $(A + B)^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are both $n\times n$ matrices, how would I prove that $(A + B)^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2$ for any $n\times n$ matrices?

Comment: You can't, otherwise you'd be proving that $2AB = AB + BA$ for all square matrices, which isn't true.

Comment: This is not true. Try to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't true in general since $A$ and $B$ might not commute. The most that we can say is
$$ (A+B)^2=(A+B)(A+B)=A^2+AB+BA+B^2 $$

Comment: Why not give a simple counter example? If $A=\left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 1\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right]$ and $B=\left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 0\\0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$, then
$(A+B)^2 =  \left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 1\\0 & 1 \end{array}\right]^2 = \left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 1\\0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$,

Comment: but $A^2 + 2AB + B^2 = \left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 1\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right]^2 + 2\left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 1\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right]\left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 0\\0 & 1 \end{array}\right] + \left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 0\\0 & 1 \end{array}\right]^2=\left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 0\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right] + 2\left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 1\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right] + \left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 0\\0 & 1 \end{array}\right] = \left [\begin{array}{l l}0 & 2\\0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$